# NSDictionary with dictionary as objects, get objects

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary like this one.

```
PhotoData =     {
    1 =         {
        "jf_photo_geotag" = "arayat philippines";
        "jf_photo_id" = 1;
        "jf_photo_url" = "http://adomainname/iphone_images/large/jf_largeimage1.png";
        "jf_user_id" = 1;
        comments =             {
            1 =                 {
                "jf_photo_comment" = "well i like this one. really. comment from janus";
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 1;
                "jf_photo_id" = 1;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            };
            4 =                 {
                "jf_photo_comment" = asasfa;
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 4;
                "jf_photo_id" = 1;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            };
        };
        likes =             {
            2 =                 {
                "jf_like_id" = 2;
                "jf_photo_id" = 1;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            };
        };
        "post_date" = "2012-02-23 16:34:14";
    };
    2 =         {
        "jf_photo_geotag" = "magalang philippines";
        "jf_photo_id" = 2;
        "jf_photo_url" = "http://adomainname/iphone_images/large/jf_largeimage2.png";
        "jf_user_id" = 2;
        comments =             {
            2 =                 {
                "jf_photo_comment" = "well this is now a comment from loaclhost! for phot number 2";
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 2;
                "jf_photo_id" = 2;
                "jf_user_id" = 2;
                "jf_username" = fidel;
            };
            3 =                 {
                "jf_photo_comment" = asdfadf;
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 3;
                "jf_photo_id" = 2;
                "jf_user_id" = 2;
                "jf_username" = fidel;
            };
        };
        likes =             {
            1 =                 {
                "jf_like_id" = 1;
                "jf_photo_id" = 2;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            };
        };
        "post_date" = "2012-02-23 16:34:31";
    };
    3 =         {
        "jf_photo_geotag" = "san fdo philippines";
        "jf_photo_id" = 3;
        "jf_photo_url" = "http://adomainname/iphone_images/large/jf_largeimage1.png";
        "jf_user_id" = 3;
        comments =             (
        );
        likes =             (
        );
        "post_date" = "2012-02-24 16:34:47";
    };
  };
success = 1;
```

}

basically, this NSDictionary contains some string data like jf_photo_url, jf_photo_id etc. and also it has another dictionary as its object like comments = ()

how can I work with this dictionary to change its structure and produce and maybe create a new Dictionary similar to this one:

```
PhotoData =     {
    {
        "jf_photo_geotag" = "arayat philippines";
        "jf_photo_id" = 1;
        "jf_photo_url" = "http://adomainname/iphone_images/large/jf_largeimage1.png";
        "jf_user_id" = 1;
        comments = (
            {
                "jf_photo_comment" = "well i like this one. really. comment from janus";
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 1;
                "jf_photo_id" = 1;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            },
            {
                "jf_photo_comment" = asasfa;
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 4;
                "jf_photo_id" = 1;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            }
        };
        likes =  (
                {
                "jf_like_id" = 2;
                "jf_photo_id" = 1;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            }
         ,"post_date" = "2012-02-23 16:34:14";
    },

    {
        "jf_photo_geotag" = "magalang philippines";
        "jf_photo_id" = 2;
        "jf_photo_url" = "http://adomainname/iphone_images/large/jf_largeimage2.png";
        "jf_user_id" = 2;
        comments =(
                {
                "jf_photo_comment" = "well this is now a comment from loaclhost! for phot number 2";
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 2;
                "jf_photo_id" = 2;
                "jf_user_id" = 2;
                "jf_username" = fidel;
            },
            {
                "jf_photo_comment" = asdfadf;
                "jf_photo_comment_id" = 3;
                "jf_photo_id" = 2;
                "jf_user_id" = 2;
                "jf_username" = fidel;
            };
        };
        likes = (
            {
                "jf_like_id" = 1;
                "jf_photo_id" = 2;
                "jf_user_id" = 1;
                "jf_username" = janus;
            };
        },
        "post_date" = "2012-02-23 16:34:31";
    },
     {
        "jf_photo_geotag" = "san fdo philippines";
        "jf_photo_id" = 3;
        "jf_photo_url" = "http://adomainname/iphone_images/large/jf_largeimage1.png";
        "jf_user_id" = 3;
        comments =             (
        );
        likes =             (
        );
        "post_date" = "2012-02-24 16:34:47";
    };
  };
success = 1;
```

}

notice that the first dictionary has index number in each object. I want to remove them.
my first dictionary is loaded from the server, the second one is from a plist

thanks you guys! I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want your outer dictionary to be an array instead. Assuming you have this data in an NSDictionary already, you could copy it to an array like so:

```
NSDictionary* photoDict = some_dict; //your outer dict
NSMutableArray* photoArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [photoDict objectEnumerator];
id value;
while((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
  [photoArray addObject:value];
}

//do something with photoArray
```

Comment: hi @badger ! yes exactly.. will try you code snippet and let  you know! thanks!